# Copy (NSManaged)Object

Tags: ios, swift, class

My `NSManagedObject` class has a property holding an `Int` serving as some sort of tag. The default value is `0` and this object is the source of my table view. The property `tag` **doesn't** have to be an `@NSManaged` variable.

```
let data: [Items] = []
```

I have implemented a way to copy a cell by dragging it:

```
let newItem = data[indexPath.row]
newItem.tag++

let newPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: indexPath.section)

data.insert(newItem, atIndex: newPath.row)
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

This won't work obviously because `tag` will be changed in the original item as well. I can fix this by wrapping `Items` in a struct or using a tuple instead. But I was hoping I can avoid this and somehow find another (more elegant way) of doing this. Any ideas?

Edit:

I forgot to mention, I don't want to create a new instance of the class.

Comment: Create and insert a new instance

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention not wanting to create a new instance. I've updated the question.